# Update user when node is created

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I'm new in Drupal 8 and I need to update the user when a node of a specific content type is created or updated.
I did some searching and I find **hook_entity_create** but this hook Act when **creating** a new entity

Comment: node is an entity...

Comment: Yes I know that, but I need to update the user after the entity(node) is created - thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()
 */
function MYMODULE_node_insert(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {

  if($node->bundle() == 'article') { //check for a content type, ex: article
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid); // load the user
    $user->set('field_name', $some_value); // set a value for a particular field
    $user->save();
  }

}
```

Originally I wrote:

<strike>`MYMODULE_node_create(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {`</strike>

Changed it as per the comment below.

Comment: I wouldn't save anything to the database in this hook because you don't know if the entity form will be submitted. Use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert() (new) or hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update() (update).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Rules* module (in alpha) to perform some actions after new content or updated content is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I clearly understand your needs, but the `hook_node_presave` lets you the option to take a different action if it's a new or an updated node. Of course, it is always a good idea to wrap it in a `try catch`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 * 
 * Acts on an node before it is created or updated.
 *
 * This hook is invoked from $node->save() before the node is saved to the
 * database.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node
 *   The node that is being inserted or updated.
 *
 */
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  // If it is the wanted content type ...
  if($node->getType() === 'my_wanted_type') {
    // ... and if what you need is the current user ...
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    // ... check if it is a new or an updated node
    $operation = $node->isNew() ? 'create' : 'update';
    // ... and call the function that will handle your needs.
    updateUserOnNodeSave($user, $operation);
  }
}

function updateUserOnNodeSave($user, $operation) {
  if(null != $user) {
    if($operation === 'create') {
      // do something meaningful with $user
    }
    elseif($operation === 'update') {
      // do something meaningful with $user
    }
    $user->save();
  }
}
```